Is there any other methods when using unsubscribe from `Subscription` in Angular/RxJS
Whenever I store the Subscription instances, I am using unsubscribe() during the ngOnDestroy life cycle in all components.
But I want to implement that within one file, so I don't have to use unsubscribe() in each component.

use takeUntilDestroyed

You can create a BaseComponent class which has a variable for subscriptions: Subscription[]; and a function which does the unsubscription. You can extend all your components with the BaseComponent and use the subscriptions variable to store your streams then in your component ngDestroy you call the BaseComponent unsubscription function.

Please further describe your specific use case and show some sample code.

As already said, takeUntilDestroyed is the most idiomatic way forward.
However, in my company we are using a base class for all components and services that need to handle unsubscribe on destroy. I still find it simpler, with less magic involved.
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AutoUnsubscribe implements OnDestroy {
  readonly autoUnsubscriber: Observable<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if ((this.autoUnsubscriber as ReplaySubject<void>).closed) return;
    (this.autoUnsubscriber as ReplaySubject<void>).next();
    (this.autoUnsubscriber as ReplaySubject<void>).complete();
  }
}

Then, you can make your components, directives or services inherit from AutoUnsubscribe, and use everywhere the takeUntil RxJS operator:
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent extends AutoUnsubscribe {
  constructor(someService: MyService) {
    super();
    
    someService.getSome$().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.autoUnsubscriber)
    ).subscribe(data => { 
      // ...
    });
  }
}

It just becomes second nature, and you don't need to define the ngOnDestroy method, which AFAICT you should with takeUntilDestroyed.
Every developer needs to just learn to check that a takeUntil is always the last operator in a pipe, just before the subscribe.
This pattern removes also most of the benefits in using the async pipe, that is very often addressed as a very good and clean way to handle subscription, but in my experience is very prone to multiple subscription problems (like multiple calls to the same api).

If you use Angular 17+, use takeUntilDestroyed
Otherwise, you can use takeUntilDestroyed as a library
Additionally, async pipes automatically unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed. IMO, you should have very few subscriptions in your components, those should be edge cases.
Finally, you can limit the emission of your observables by using operators like first, take, takeUntil and such. It is very unlikely that you have tons of observables that emit continuously, and you need to subscribe to all of them. Consider reworking your workflows/code to make it more efficient.
